# Search Similar SKU number in Column A and Add QTY in Column 2

Tags: excel, vba

I have data Data to analyse

[image: Data to analyse]

What I need is to

1. Analyse data in "SKU" ans "pieces" column from one worksheet
2. Type Similar "SKU" once in column 1 and add respective "pieces" in column  2 to another worksheet

Table shall look like as required after running macro

[image: As required after running macro]

I have no idea from where to start.

Comment: This is called a Pivot Table.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this …

#### … either with a formula

```
=SUMIF(A:A,A:A,B:B)
```

[image]

#### … or by adding a PivotTable

[image]

Therefore select the data `SUK` and `Pieces` and select from the ribbon menu Insert › PivotTable and check both fields (see image below).

[image]

Comment: I want to automate all SKU values , these may be in 100 or 1000, and I will be unable to type manually
I want a command button , that analyse all similar sku in column 1(say there are 5 rows) , copy and paste to another worksheet in a single row.
After this, from respective column 2 of SKU, all number of pieces are added and pasted to new worksheet in single row

Comment: @BabyCare I didn't tell you to do that. You don't need to type manually you can just type the formula once and copy it down. Or better use the PivotTable.

Comment: Pivot Table will not solve the problem, I have 2 files, "Magaya" and "Sage", both have same SKU names but different pieces
i need to compare both , these steps include
Import SKU from Magaya to another worksheet
Import "Pieces" from "Magaya"
Import "Pieces" from "Sage" against SKU in new worksheet

There will be many same sku name rows, we need to analyse and write it once, and add pieces respective to each SKU 

I hope it will make some clear view

Comment: @BabyCare Well this is a correct answer to the question you asked. If you ask the wrong question you cannot expect to get another answer. • Note that this is no free code writing service since you did nothing yet this a way to broad to answer. • My recommendation is: 1. write the formula I gave you with VBA, 2. convert it into values, 3. use the remove duplicates feature to remove duplicate SUKs and finally 4. delete column B. • You will find tutorials for each of these 4 steps so give it a try on your own and if you get stuck ask a new question here on Stack Overflow providing your code.

Answer (score 0):

I just can't understand why people never mention Excel's `Subtotal` feature, showing this result: :-)

[image]

In order to achieve this, go to the `Data` tab, and in the `Outline` part (the mostright one), you have the `Subtotal` feature, where you can use it.

By the way, I clicked on the `2` in the left margin, in order just to see those subtotals.